# Build YouTube app (Webapp)

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

How I build YouTubeapp 
For example: that UITableView display YouTube home page like as offical YouTube app and UIImage display the photo of video how do it

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly do you want? Your question is unclear... Is it a problem of conception?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you use `UITableView`, that's not a webapp.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [step by step tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-make-a-youtube-app-using-mgbox-and-jsonmodel/) to do what you want buddy. And you can download their source code from [github](https://github.com/JSONModel/YouTubeBrowserDemo)